# Installing Torch7 on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS x64: "Error: Build error: Failed compiling object readline.o"

Tags: torch

I followed the instructions from http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html to install Torch on Torch7 on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.

```
# in a terminal, run the commands
sudo apt-get install -y cmake # is needed to compile when running ./install.sh
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-deps | bash
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch; ./install.sh
```

When executing `./install.sh` it failed with this error message:

```
Error: Build error: Failed compiling object readline.o
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue you need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libreadline-dev
```

then remove the build folder (otherwise it will give another error: `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`) and run the installation commands again.